# How to achieve a layout in Android studio with two Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am trying to achieve the below layout but I am not sure how I can split / have two layouts on one screen, with one being empty and one containing other elements. Like shown in the image below, I want to have layout 1 that contains other elements and layout that is empty. With a divider line between the two layouts.

[image]

Any help would be nice, I am not sure where to start. I have came accross having two layouts on 1 screen and splitting them to about 40:60 ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.rushabh_pc.lin.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Label2"
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:checked="false" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Label 3"
    android:id="@+id/lab3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/toggleButton" />
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Label 4"
       android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lab3"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lab3"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/toggleButton"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/toggleButton"
       android:id="@+id/l4"/>

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="last"
       android:layout_below="@id/l4"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I will try this now and will let you know.

Comment: How can I put text boxes instead of textview please for label 3 and 4 and a divider between the two layouts

Comment: Also, I want to have 2 layouts

Answer (score 0):

Use LinearLayout with layout_weight to specify the ratio for the space occupied by each child layout. For a 40:60 split, use the below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:text="Label"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:text="Label"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:hint="Textbox1" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:hint="Textbox2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:text="Label" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.6"></LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. how can I position the textvew and textboxes as shown in the picture. I am struggling with that

Comment: @JollyKupli, Your question is related to having two layouts with a 40:60 split. Anyway, I've updated the answer to also position the Textviews and EditTexts like in your question. If this provides a solution, mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

**Code Below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.staff.app.Main3Activity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="textView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="textView"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLyout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="editText1"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="editText2"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="textView"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLyout"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"></View>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: this is how it looks!]